# Is possible to list the git repository issues in command line?

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

When fixing an issue I want to make sure that I close the correct issue writing in the commit message: `"Fixed #issueId"`.

To be faster I would like to list the repository issues in terminal. Is this possible with a `git` command?

I imagine something like below:

```
$ git issues --all

+---------------------------------------+
| Repository Name - Issues              |
+---------------------------------------+
| # | Title                   | Status  |
+---------------------------------------+
| 1 | Lorem Ipsum 1           | OPEN    |
| 2 | Lorem Ipsum 2           | WONTFIX |
| 3 | Lorem Ipsum 3           | RESOLVED|
| 4 | Lorem Ipsum 4           | INVLID  |
+---------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check out mine as well: https://npmjs.org/package/git-issues

```
npm install -g git-issues
```

It also works from a cloned location if you add the `bin/git-issues` it to your PATH.

It supports both GitHub and BitBucket. It displays by default `open` issues. For `closed` issues run:

```
git issues -s closed
```

Feel free to fork my repo and send a pull request with more features.

Comment: Not working any more? When I run `npm i -g git-issues` as suggested at https://www.npmjs.com/package/git-issues, I get `npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated`, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142.

Comment: This worked nicely to list the issues, does it also allow showing the content of the issues? *I did not find a method to do so in the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/git-issues)

Answer (score 4):

No, not directly with the "vanilla" git command line.

There is a "command-line wrapper for git that makes you better at GitHub." (according to the site)

http://hub.github.com/

You can then run:

`$ git browse -- issues`

Which would return the current projects issues.

**EDIT**
In that case, [this](https://github.com/stephencelis/ghi) may be more helpful.

It's a cli to github

Comment: I installed it but when I type this command it opens the browser. I want to list them in terminal (see my Question edit).

Comment: Sorry, i pasted the wrong link. Correct is https://github.com/stephencelis/ghi - edited answer

Comment: As a heads up, Hub supports getting lists of issues and PRs in the terminal now. 

`hub issue` and `hub pr list/checkout`. 

Observed from [here](https://blog.alexellis.io/building-a-linux-desktop-for-cloud-native-development/).